# Internationalization gone wrong in gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

ERROR #95313 Building static HTML failed for path "/404/"

I recently implemented localization in my gatsby project using the react-intl package. I was able to pull that off by mimicking the implementation of the package in the  [gatsby-starter-default-contentful-i18n](https://github.com/mccrodp/gatsby-starter-contentful-i18n) repo. Everything works fine when I run gatsby-develop but sadly not the same after running build.

The react-intl packages require some route configurations to get it up and running, which made me make use of the location props in my layout component which is exposed to the route paths which I also implemented using the earlier linked repo as a guide. However, I always meet this error.

```
const url = location.pathname;
    |                            ^
36 |       const { langs, defaultLangKey } = data.site.siteMetadata.languages;
37 |       const langKey = getCurrentLangKey(langs, defaultLangKey, url);
38 |       const homeLink = `/${langKey}/`;

-WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined.
```

I keep getting pointed towards the url variable. I made sure to cross-check all the location props that were passed down from layout component parents to make sure none of them were undefined, but still no dice. I really don't know where to start debugging this problem.
Below is my index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql, navigate, withPrefix } from 'gatsby';
import { getUserLangKey } from 'ptz-i18n';

class RedirectIndex extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(args) {
    super(args);

    // Skip build, Browsers only
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const { langs, defaultLangKey } = args.data.site.siteMetadata.languages;
      const langKey = getUserLangKey(langs, defaultLangKey);
      const homeUrl = withPrefix(`/${langKey}/`);

      navigate(homeUrl);
    }
  }

  render() {
    // It's recommended to add your SEO solution in here for bots
    // eg. https://github.com/ahimsayogajp/ahimsayoga-gatsby/blob/master/src/pages/index.js#L22
    return (<div />);
  }
}

export default RedirectIndex;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {
    site{
      siteMetadata{
        languages {
          defaultLangKey
          langs
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!